# Is there a queryable table of the privileges supported by a MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm writing a program that needs to know what privileges a MySQL server supports. This differs between MySQL versions, so I would like to do something like `SELECT Privilege FROM PRIVILEGES` and get a table of privileges that my program can parse through. `SHOW PRIVILEGES` is similar to what I want except I can't do `SELECT` statements on the results. Is there any way I can get a table of all privileges supported by a MySQL version?

Comment: What do you mean that you want to run a `SELECT` on `SHOW PRIVILEGES`? That query already gives you a result set you can use.

Comment: What I mean is that I would like to select only the Privilege column from the 'SHOW PRIVILEGES' table.

Comment: How are you reading the data from MySQL? Is it possible that you read all the columns but don't _use_ the columns you don't need?

Comment: I'm reading it through .NET and parsing it in C#. I think it is possible to just read the whole table and only use the one column I need. I won't be able to try it until tomorrow, but that does sound like the correct solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Turns out that my issue is being caused by a bug in my code preventing me from creating a DataTable using the `SHOW` statement. I haven't fixed the bug yet, but I am able to store the rows in a List<string[]> and access them that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SHOW PRIVILEGES` returns a table of the privileges supported by a MySQL server version. The reason I couldn't access the rows in C# was due to a bug in my code.